# GetEnumerator throws ArgumentException on Windows with WinRT

Tags: .net, com, windows-runtime, marshalling, ienumerable

I оbtain xmlCollection through com objects and try to use foreach with the obtained collection. That invokes this

`System.ArgumentException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetComObjectData(Object obj, Object key)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumerableToDispatchMarshaler.MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
   at System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 Message: The object's type must not be a Windows Runtime type.`

Code fails in [Marshal.GetComObejectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getcomobjectdata(v=vs.110).aspx) inside logic GetEnumerator(). I suppose it happens because system mixes Com and winRt objects, but tottally misunderstand how to resolve problem.

I would like to pay attention that obtained and casted collection in windows 10 has type Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList. It's winRt type

And the most important thing that the problem exists only on Windows with WinRT (win 8,10, 2012). On windows 7 everything is fine.

Here Interface which i use to cast com object to managed code. `this[index]`  and `Count` works well and I can appeal to these but GetEnumerator fails

```
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface INewList:IEnumerable
{

  [DispId(0)]
  IXMLDOMNode this[int index]
  {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0)]
    get;
  }


  [DispId(0x4a)]
  int Count
  {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x4a)]
    get;
  }
}
```

this is interface  I using to  obtain collection

```
[ComImport, Guid("1933BF91-7B36-11D2-B20E-00104F983E60"), TypeLibType((short) 0x10c0)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IDom
{
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x1d)]
   INodeList SelectNodes([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string queryString);
}
```

If I missed important facts for understanding the problem please ask me

thanks

Comment: How do you obtain the COM object in question on which the GetEnumerator() call fails?

Comment: Sunius, I updated post and answered on your question

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea why it fails to work - you'd need to debug CoreCLR (which is public btw) on both windows 7 machines and windows 10 machines and see where it goes wrong. Anyway, I can suggest a workaround: write a class that wraps your collection and implements IEnumerable over indexers.